# How to interpret tauB parameter in JMBayes output

Tags: r, bayesian, mixed-model, predictive-models, survival

```
library(JMbayes);library(splines)        
lmeFit.pbc <- lme(log(serBilir) ~ ns(year, 2),
    random = list(id = pdDiag(form = ~ ns(year, 2))), data = pbc2)
survFit.pbc <- coxph(Surv(years, status2) ~ 1, data = pbc2.id, x = TRUE)
jointFit.pbc <- jointModelBayes(lmeFit.pbc, survFit.pbc, timeVar = "year")
summary(jointFit.pbc)
```

From the summary of jointFit.pbc:

```
Call:
jointModelBayes(lmeObject = lmeFit.pbc, survObject = survFit.pbc, 
    timeVar = "year")

Data Descriptives:
Longitudinal Process        Event Process
Number of Observations: 1945    Number of Events: 140 (44.9%)
Number of subjects: 312

Joint Model Summary:
Longitudinal Process: Linear mixed-effects model
Event Process: Relative risk model with penalized-spline-approximated 
        baseline risk function
Parameterization: Time-dependent value 

      LPML      DIC       pD
 -3130.168 6024.854 922.3928

Variance Components:
              StdDev    Corr        
(Intercept)   1.0034  (Intr)  n(,2)1
ns(year, 2)1  2.1113  0.2328        
ns(year, 2)2  2.0581  0.0405  0.3964
Residual      0.3026                

Coefficients:
Longitudinal Process
              Value Std.Err Std.Dev   2.5%  97.5%      P
(Intercept)  0.5107  0.0013  0.0570 0.3998 0.6197 <0.001
ns(year, 2)1 2.0177  0.0076  0.1463 1.7384 2.3114 <0.001
ns(year, 2)2 1.5409  0.0127  0.1644 1.2317 1.8926 <0.001

Event Process
          Value Std.Err  Std.Dev    2.5%     97.5%      P
Assoct   1.3006  0.0103   0.1064  1.0954    1.5127 <0.001
tauBs  433.9452 24.4804 277.8596 85.1953 1143.4011     NA

MCMC summary:
iterations: 20000 
adapt: 3000 
burn-in: 3000 
thinning: 10 
time: 3.9 min
```

This is my unfamiliarity with Bayesian methods showing, but I am not certain how I should interpret the tauBs term. From the help page of jointModelBayes, "priorA.tauBs
the prior shape parameter of the Gamma prior for the precision parameter of the penalty term when baseHaz = "P-splines"". However I am uncertain what I should be looking for when examining this parameter.